# Create a table who's name must be a primary key in another table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can force my MySQL database to allow creation of a new table with name table_xyz, only if a record with table_xyz exists in another table?

Basically I want my table name to be a foreign key.

e.g. allowed_tables structure:

```
table_id | other columns |
--------------------------
table_xyz| bla bla bla   |
--------------------------
```

Because I have a record with table_xyz in allowed_tables, I can create a table with this name. If I delete the record, the table should automatically be deleted. The same must happen if I change the table name.

**Edit 1:**

The table allowed_structures actually is called loans. It contains loan_id, and other columns required on the contract. After I insert this record, I create a table with the name < loan_id > ( a record which must exists in loans table). If I update/ delete a record with < loan_id > in loans table, I want that table name to be changed automatically, not via a PHP script. Currently is done via a PHP script.

I need to know which is the best option to do this and why. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to reread up on database design.

Comment: It sounds to me like bad design, but you can try create/update/delete new tables using trigger for your source table.

Comment: I suggest using a different identifier than the name, make a unique identifier for the loans table that is not as modifiable as name is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was originally written for SQL Server, but concept is same for every RDBMS.

Yes it is achievable, but [Curse and Blessing Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl)

> **CREATE TABLE @tbl**
>
> The desire here is to create a table of which the name is determined at run-time.
>
> If we just look at the arguments against using dynamic SQL in stored procedures, few of them are really applicable here. If a stored procedure has a static CREATE TABLE in it, the user who runs the procedure must have permissions to create tables, so dynamic SQL will not change anything. Plan caching obviously has nothing to do with it. Etc.
>
> Nevertheless: Why? Why would you want to do this? **If you are creating tables on the fly in your application, you have missed some fundamentals about database design. In a relational database, the set of tables and columns are supposed to be constant. They may change with the installation of new versions, but not during run-time.**

**EDIT:**

In SQL Server I would use trigger for source table (`FOR INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`) and using `Dynamic-SQL` I can achieve exactly what you want, but still I think this is *madness*.

If you want to go this path check if MySQL supports the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated mine to show the purpose of creating new tables which names must exists in another table.