# create table column based on another table column value in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

is there any possibility to create table column base on another table column value?
existing table(geozone) would look like this and it is not fixed(can contain more id and name)

```
id | name
1  | UK
2  | CANADA
3  | JAPAN
```

and i am trying to create new one from php page

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE shipping (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `shipping_cost` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
        )");
```

the query above create shipping table successfully but that's not what i need, how can i create shipping_cost column has an id of geozone id?
 example: shipping_cost_1, shipping_cost_2 and shipping_cost_3

Comment: Yes it is possible but creating table/columns at runtime is bad design. **[See my today answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422071/create-a-table-whos-name-must-be-a-primary-key-in-another-table/32422209#32422209)**

Comment: its only execute only when clicked on install(not need to explain), btw how do i write the query?

Comment: how many shipping zones do you have? Perhaps a bad design

Comment: @drew, i can say it depend on how many they have, can be less/more than that. they also can add/remove geozone if they would like, i just put 3 as example to my question

Comment: problem is, if you have 26, and your live is spent in `ALTER TABLE` with NULLS, and all that maintenance at the product-level. It doesn't scale, and the housekeeping would be quite a chore. The chore will be quite a chore regardless, the point is to make it fast and minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the shipping cost depends on the product and the geozone it's sent to, which means a `geozone_id` column needs to be added to your `shipping_cost` table. Also add a unique constraint on `(geozone_id,product_id)` because each unique pair should have only one shipping cost.

```
CREATE TABLE shipping (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `geozone_id` int(11) NOT NULL, -- specify which geozone this cost is for
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `shipping_cost` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    -- UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), -- Not necessary because Primary keys are already unique 
    UNIQUE KEY `product_id_geozone_id` (`product_id`,`geozone_id`) -- each product, geozone can only have 1 cost
)
```

Then you can select the cost for each product/geozone pair with a join:

```
select geozone.name, product.name,
shipping.shipping_cost
from products
join shipping on shipping.product_id = product.id
join geozone on shipping.geozone_id = geozone.id
```